this.$emit('update:page', 1); doesnt work on production
Does anyone have any idea why adding this.$emit('update:page', 1); doesn't work on beta, but does it work on locale?
Page from index.blade.php goes to @include('public.components.filters.filter', ['liveLoad' => true, 'isFilterPage' => true]), and from there to <sort> via :page.sync="page"
is further changed using this.$emit('update:page', 1);
index.blade.php has page variable:
......
@include('public.components.filters.filter', ['liveLoad' => true, 'isFilterPage' => true])
......

filter.blade.php has vue template component:
.........
<div class="controls__item controls__item_sort">
  <sort
     :page.sync="page"
     :sort_direction.sync="sort_direction"
     :sort_type.sync="sort_type"
     :sorts="filterSettings.sorts"
     :type-sale="typeSale"
   ></sort>
</div>
.........

sort.vue:
name: "sort",
props: ['sort_direction', 'sort_type', 'sorts', 'typeSale', 'page'],
data() {
   return {
       title: undefined,
       tests: {},
   }
},
methods: {

..........
        changeSorts(direction, type, title) {
            this.title = title;
            this.$emit('update:sort_direction', direction);
            this.$emit('update:sort_type', type);
            console.log(this.page);
            this.$emit('update:page', 1);
            console.log(this.page);
            this.close();
        },


I cleaned the cache, updated the browser via ctrl+f5. Also enabled/disabled cache in the browser.

how is it not working exactly?  are you listening for the event anywhere?
